# How does the svn repository use HD space?

Tags: svn

Let's explain how my repository looks like:

```
repository  
|  trunk  
|  |  folder_1  
|  |  |  file_x  
|  |  folder_2
```

I want to execute the `svn mv` command on `file_x` in order to transfer that file from `folder_1` to `folder_2`. The `file_x` has 100MB. So, if i use the `svn mv` command, in my repository there will be 2 references of `file_x`, one in `folder_1` (deleted) and one in `folder_2` (added).

My question is: my repository will use 100MB or 200MB of my HD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This move will not take up a lot of space in your repository.

When you do a `svn mv`, it only makes a link from the old to new location. This is why Subversion can follow the history of a file as it moves from location to location. If you use URLs for the move, the whole process takes just a fraction of a second:

```
$ svn mv -m"Moving file_x around" \
    http://repository/trunk/folder_1/file_x \
    http://repository/trunk/folder_2
```

However, I do have to ask why `file_x` is so large. I take it it's a binary file. You should try not to store binary files in your repository because:

- They take up a lot of room (An average Java source code project takes up about 200K to 400K in source code. That 100Mb file represents 200 to 500 Java projects!).
- They don't version nicely (Subversion tries to store stuff in diff format. Each file change might take up 2 to 10K in space. When you add a second revision of that binary file, you'll take up another 90Mb to 100Mb of space.
- The history doesn't tell you much. (All you know is who checked in this version of a file. Not what is the actual difference between one revision and another and why there was a change).

In the end, you'll end up finding that your repository becomes 95% binary files that you really don't care about. There are usually better ways of storing binary files. For example, if you do Java development, and most of these are jar files, you can use Ivy or Maven to retrieve them. If you are trying to store built binaries, you can use Jenkins.

---

## Addendum

> So, versioning binary files is not a good practice? because im a configuration manager and im managing 5 projects repositories. Some of those projects work with videos and images creation.

Yes, binary files take up a lot of room. A golden rule in Version Control is *Never store binary files*. You can add that to the *Big o' Book of Golden Rules for Version Control* right after this golden rule:

- All rules can be broken.

For example, we had a Java project with a lot of help files. These were built by a system called Robohelp that took Microsoft Word documents and created a bunch of HTML files that could be used for help. Even the most minor change in the initial Word documents created hundreds of HTML files with completely different name. We built on Linux, and the whole help system was built on Windows (See Microsoft Word).

Originally, the project tried storing the generated HTML files, but do to the constantly shifting name, sizes, and other issues, it became a pain.

I thought of storing the Microsoft Word files (which are binaries themselves), but I would have no way to generate the help files on a Linux system. We needed those HTML files for a build. What do we do?

I decided to store the original Word documents, and a zipped up copy of the generated HTML help files in Subversion. This broke all sorts of rules of good version control management. However, the help rarely changed, and the zipped archive meant we had a single help file that had to be changed each time instead of adding and deleting hundreds. The entire zip was about 15K. It worked, and we simply couldn't come up with a better solution.

Having never worked on a video project, I'll be *conjecturing* here. That means I am just pulling stuff out of a part of my anatomy that doesn't get a lot of sun shine.

How does your video projects work? Is there some *build language* that takes all of your video clips, sound resources, etc and puts them together.  If so, it's obvious that the final project shouldn't be stored, but instead, you'll store your clips somewhere, and *build* your project.

I have a feeling that the project is kept in a big massive file with all of the links to the needed resources that are stored separately. Do the various bits and pieces change? I can imagine editing a sound clip to improve clarity, add effects, etc. You might want to keep that history. Or maybe one project uses the older version of that clip while another project uses a newer version. Maybe these clips do have to be under version control.

Maybe the entire project with all of its resources is kept under a single project file. I might import clips from a library, but the actual project is that 100Mb `file_x` you talked about before.

Source control does is not just keep file history, but keeps the file history across hundreds, maybe of thousands of files in sync. It doesn't do much good if your project depends up 2000 files if you don't know which versions of those files go together. There's that and branching which allows for multiple development streams. If you're not dealing with synchronizing versions of files across an entire project, or multiple development streams, you might not need a true source control system.

**NetApps** is a high availability system that allows for snapshotting and reverting to older versions of files. It's fast, and rugged. This is why it's popular in many data shops. We had one where we stored databases. We could run a test on a database, then revert the changes and run the test over. The whole revision process on that 90Gb database took 4 1/2 seconds.

And, NetApps can be had for as low as a few million dollars! Plus, if you ask nicely, they'll throw in a t-shirt. (Mention my name, and maybe I'll get a t-shirt too!). Not in the budget of a typical video studio?

**Dropbox** also does file history snapshotting and tracking. You can even restore a file that had been previously deleted. For $10 per month, you get 1 terabyte of storage and a system that tracks all file changes (including adds and deletes) for an entire year. However, there's no t-shirt.

**Google**, **Microsoft**, **Amazon**, and soon **Apple** have similar services at similar prices. Each has its own advantages and ways of working. Most allow for trials or have free services where you get a mere few 10s of gigabytes of storage that you can try.

It's hard to know what will work best for you. Maybe Subversion is the best way to go, and you'll simply have to deal with an extremely large Subversion repository (100s of gigabytes in size) after a year of multiple projects and changes. Some other version control systems have the ability to *obliterate* obsolete files and versions to save room. One of those might work better.

Think about what your needs are, and figure out what might work best for you.

Comment: So, versioning binary files is not a good practice? because im a configuration manager and im managing 5 projects repositories. Some of those projects work with videos and images creation.

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't use 200MB of your HD (you could just try that out). Even with `svn cp` subversion won't create a new file but internally use something like a unix hardlink. See also http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.using.html:

> [...] Subversion continues to employ this hard link concept where it can. It duplicates data only when it is necessary to disambiguate different versions of objects. [...]